# Is there DocumentDB Role based Access control (RBAC) with regex database support?

Tags: mongodb, aws-documentdb

Does MongoDB/Document DB support creating user and assign it to roles like(`readWrite`) to certain databases whose name follows certain patterns (like `nonprod_*`).